# Throws rule in java

Tags: java, exception, throws

These days, I have been trying to learn java, But I am confused about Throws exceptions. is this statement correct?: Throws in method signature causes an exception (or some exceptions) throw to another method that is calling this method. and caller method has try/catch to handle thrown exception.

Thanks in advance.
Farrohk

Comment: [Check this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither statement is correct.

> Throws in method signature causes an exception (or some exceptions) throw to another method that is calling this method

Declaring that a method `throws` an exception just indicates that it *might* throw the exception, not that it does.

> and caller method has try/catch to handle thrown exception.

The caller can declare that it throws the same exception, rather than try/catching, so the exception is propagated to that method's caller.

Comment: Thank you, suppose we have _method_ which declare by throws an exception that it might throw the exception. Now if the _method_ throw an exception, what will happen? Where would be handle that exception? If nothing will happen  then there is no reason to declare this _method_ by throws.

Comment: It will have to be handled by its caller, either `catch`ing it or propagation via `throws`, which passes the burden of handling the exception onto the caller's caller. My second point is just saying that try/catch is not the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Throws clause in used to declare an exception and thow keyword is used to throw an exception explicitly.

This [link](http://crunchify.com/what-is-a-difference-between-throw-vs-throws-in-java/) which has good information about the difference between throws and throw can help you improve your understanding.